# Pytesseract Image_to_string returns Windows Error: Access denied error in Python

Tags: python-2.7, tesseract, python-tesseract, windowserror

I tried to read the text from the image using Pytesseract.I am getting Access denied message when I run the below script.

```
     from PIL import Image
     import pytesseract
     import cv2
     import os

     filename=r'C:\Users\ychandra\Documents\teaching-text-structure-3-728.jpg'
     pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pytesseract'
     image=cv2.imread(filename)
     gray=cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

     gray=cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY|cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
     gray=cv2.medianBlur(gray,3)

     filename='{}.png'.format(os.getpid())
     cv2.imwrite(filename,gray)

     text=pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename))
     print text

     cv2.imshow("image",image)
     cv2.imshow("res",gray)
     cv2.waitKey(0)
```

when I run the script  I am getting below Error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "F:\opencv\New_folder_3\text_from_image.py", line 17, in <module>
text=pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename))
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 122, in image_to_string
config=config)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 46, in run_tesseract
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 640, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
    WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code works except the setting of `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd`. The `tesseract_cmd` should set to the `tesseract executable file` installed in your machine.

Here is a sample usage of it.

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "C:/Program Files/Tesseract 4.0.0/tesseract.exe"
```

The `tesseract_cmd` is required if no properly search `PATH` setup in your Windows PC.

Hope this help.

**UPDATE:**

You need to have `tesseract` binary installed into your PC before using `pytesseract` which uses `subprocess` module to run tesseract in Windows shell from Python.

Click this [Tesseract 4.00 alpha](http://digi.bib.uni-mannheim.de/tesseract/tesseract-ocr-setup-4.00.00dev.exe) to download a 64-bit Windows version and install it. Then setup the `PATH` and `TESSDATA_PREFIX` pointing to your `tesseract.exe` and `~\tessdata` directory respectively.
[image]

If you need any other language `trained data file`, you can get it [[here]](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Data-Files#data-files-for-version-400-november-29-2016).

In case the `~\tessdata` directory is not found in your Windows, you can create it manually and copy at least one `traineddata` file to there, such as `eng.traineddata` for English.

If `tesseract` is working, it will return the version information when you type `tesseract -v` in command prompt as below. 
[image]

Comment: I tried with setting the tesseract executable file path to tesseract_cmd as you mentioned above.I am getting a different error as below.

Comment: `raise TesseractError(status, errors)
TesseractError: (1, u'Error opening data file \\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\pytesseract\\tessdata/eng.traineddata')`

Comment: I don't have that testdata folder in my pytesseract  .I installed pytesseract using PIP. Do you know where i can find it.

Comment: @chandrakanthChandra you may check my reply in the UPDATE above.

Comment: Thanks.I will check this

Comment: @chandrakanthChandra  You are welcome. Good to know the answer helps.

Comment: my tesseract works but I still recieve same error in my code