# Python Tesseract

Tags: python, tesseract

I am trying to extract text from an image using Tesseract. Here is my code. I installed using `pip install pytesseract` and I also checked pytesseract.py under site-package. But when I run the following code, I got the following error message  `'WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified'.`

Any ideas? Thanks

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
#pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract.cmd = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe'
im = Image.open('C:/Users/daizhang/Desktop/issue.PNG')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string (im)
print (text)
```

Comment: I believe your only issue is that the file can't be found on the computer (the error message says that it can't find the file). Make sure that path to issue.png is correct (have you verified that it is on the desktop?). The issue does not seem to be with pytesseract but with the location of the file you are trying to load into PIL.

Comment: I don't think its simple path issue. This issue is being discussed on  `pytesseract` github @ https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract/issues/50 with some possible work-around, although the workaround didnt work for me when I tried.

Comment: @Anil_M Thanks for replying. It seems I had a typo... if I include commenting off line and change tesseract.cmd to tesseract_cmd, then it works fine.

Comment: You may check the answer in this [Pytesseract Image_to_string returns Windows Error: Access denied error in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46567157/pytesseract-image-to-string-returns-windows-error-access-denied-error-in-python)

Comment: Have you installed tesseract too and is your application in the system environment path?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that there is not enough information in the error. But you need to install [Tesseract-OCR](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract)

And also make sure the installation directory in your system path.