# pytesseract WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, access-denied

I have installed pytesseract in Windows 10 system. When I try to run the following line,

`pytesser=pytesseract.image_to_string(image)`

It throws an error saying,

`WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied`

Even after changing the tesseract_cmd path, it throws the same error.

Looking for the other possible ways to sort this issue.TIA

Comment: Do you have tesseract installed in your machine , Just give a try to `c:\>tesseract` , and check you are correct output there

Comment: It worked when I set the exact .exe path. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Your code works except the setting of pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd. The tesseract_cmd should set to the **tesseract executable** file installed in your machine. Check if it's pointing to that

See if this helps

[Pytesseract Image_to_string returns Windows Error: Access denied error in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46567157/pytesseract-image-to-string-returns-windows-error-access-denied-error-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

I also suffering this WinError5 Access denial problem in 2020 even with the tesseract executable path set-up in Windows 10, Python 3.7 and  tesseract-ocr-w64-setup-v5.0.0-alpha.20200223.exe from https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki in Anaconda.

This solution works for me.

1. Uninstall tesseract
2. Run installer as administrator (Right click the installer as select run-as)

Comment: Did not work for me.